# sqlContext.read.option(...).mongo() fails when authentication required

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark

I am using SparkSession, SQLContext and DataFrame.
And so, this code works.

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/nasa.eva2")
  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://127.0.0.1/nasa.astronautTotals")
  .getOrCreate()
val sqlContext: SQLContext = sparkSession.sqlContext

val evadf: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.option("collection", "eva2").mongo()
evadf.printSchema()
```

It will print the schema.

But same code with different URIs fails when I point to a MongoDB setup that requires authentication.

```
val sparkSession: SparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
  .master("local")
  .appName("MongoSparkConnectorIntro")
  .config("spark.mongodb.input.uri", "mongodb://m103-admin:m103-pass@192.168.103.100:27000/nasa.eva2?authSource=admin")
  .config("spark.mongodb.output.uri", "mongodb://m103-admin:m103-pass@192.168.103.100:27000/nasa.astronautTotals?authSource=admin")
.getOrCreate()
val sqlContext: SQLContext = sparkSession.sqlContext

val evadf: DataFrame = sqlContext.read.option("collection", "eva2").mongo()
evadf.printSchema()
```

Why?

I am using the following

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
    <version>3.6.3</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongo-spark-connector_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
    <artifactId>spark-sql_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: How does it fail? What error response do you get?

Comment: I must be going crazy. This morning the code is working perfectly.

Comment: Glad to see you got it working